# loading texts from XML into flash AS3?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have this XML that shows some data from mysql database.

I need to pull some of those data (i.e. Name, Price, etc) from the xml and show them in the Flash application.

Now, I can pull the images and display them in the flash but I have problem displaying the texts from the xml into the flash.

This is the structure of my xml:

```
<Data>
<ID>127</ID>
<Name>Example 1</Name>
<Price>12!!</Price>
<Image>inventory_images/127.jpg</Image>
<Date>Mar 08, 2013</Date>
</Data>
```

and this the code (Flash AS3) that will display the image of the product in the flash.

```
stop();
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var xmlLoader:URLLoader;
var xml:XML;
var xmlList:XMLList;



var uRequest = new URLRequest("PATH-TO-MY-XML-FILE");
xmlLoader = new URLLoader(uRequest);
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoad);
var imgLoader:Loader;


function onXMLLoad(e:Event) {
    xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    imgLoader = new Loader();
    imgLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onImgLoaded);
    imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(xml.Data.Image.text()[0]));
}


function onImgLoaded(e:Event) {
    addChild(imgLoader);
    imgLoader.height = 300;
    imgLoader.width = 300;
}
```

could someone please help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a complete URL into your `Image` property. And, there was a duplicate question that stated there was a security event with the folder, check this also.

Comment: sorry I didn't get your answer at all.. if you are referring to the last question, that was for pulling the images and showing them in the flash. This question is totally different subject.... please read the question again...

Comment: `xml.data.ID.text()[0]` does not work? It should retrieve `127`.

Comment: No, it doesn't work unfortunately. I've tried putting imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(xml.Data.ID.text()[0])); bellow imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(xml.Data.Image.text()[0])); and I get this error: Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.

Comment: You should trace the corresponding text first, then. Perhaps there's garbage. Don't put whatever you get into an URLRequest before evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your question correctly, the image loading and displaying part works.
If you want to display your text you can simply use TextFields like this :

```
function onXMLLoad(e:Event) {
    xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    tf.text = xml.Name.text()[0];//or whatever part you want to display
    addChild(tf);//you'll want to style and move tf, maybe.
}
```

flex labels would work too...

EDIT : also I see you are in the timeline, so you could simply use a dynamic textfield named 'myTextField' for example, and then your code :

```
var myString:String = 'loading';
function onXMLLoad(e:Event) {
    xml = new XML(e.target.data);
    myTextField.text =  "" + xml.Name.text()[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try imgLoader.load(new URLRequest(xml.Image.toString()));
and you may need use full url like http://yoursite.com/inventory_images/127.jpg instead inventory_images/127.jpg in your xml, or add http://yoursite.com/ to url string.

Comment: can you please explain this a bit further. do I need to just change that bit of the code or do I need to do anything else? Cheers

Comment: and I did try your suggestion but i got this error: Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.

Comment: you can use as-is. try add server name: `imgLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://yoursite.com/" + xml.Image.toString()));`

Comment: Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 22 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before semicolon.
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 22 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before rightparen.
Getting these errors on your line of code mate.

Comment: Now I get this error: Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2124: Loaded file is an unknown type. lol

Comment: trace it `trace(xml.Image.toString());` before imgLoader.load and open result in browser.